# How to sum in sql DB2

Tags: sql

so I have a table calls orders for example in this table I have these values

```
   name    volume    price
1- Cisco    300       27
2- Cisco    150       26
3- Cisco     50       26
```

I am trying to use this query:

```
select o.name, sum(o2.volume), o.price
from orders o, orders o2
where o.price <= o2.price
group by o.name, o.price
```

but this query returns this:

```
   name    volume    price
1- Cisco    300       27
2- Cisco    200       26
```

But I want this results:

```
   name    volume    price
1- Cisco    300       27
2- Cisco    500       26
```

In second row should be the sum of sales of:
sales with bigger price (1) + sum of all sales with lower price (2+3)

Comment: Can you elaborate -- price <= the last one where price is 26 -- why would that include 27?  Or are you trying to get all but the last record?

Comment: You didn't provide enough data to reach your results.  Why did `2- Cisco` increase its volume from 150 to 500?  What is the relation between each row?  What information are you trying to get with this query?  (If there are "sales", do you want "all sales with a lower price than their previous volume"?)

Comment: in second row should be the sum of sales of:
sales with bigger price(1-)
plus sum of all sales with lower price (2+3). get it?

Comment: How is that not "sum of all sales"?

Comment: so I have a table calls orders for example in this table I have these values
   name    volume    price
1- Cisco    300       27
2- Cisco    150       26
3- Cisco     50       26

I am trying to use this query:

select o.name, sum(o2.volume), o.price
from orders o, orders o2
where o.price <= o2.price
group by o.name, o.price

but this query returns this:

   name    volume    price
1- Cisco    300       27
2- Cisco    200       26

But I want this results:

   name    volume    price
1- Cisco    300       27
2- Cisco    500       26

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built in function to get the previous row, however you can sort your data and use window function to get the `row_number()`, and then use a `case` statement.

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER` tells DB2 how you want the rows numbered. If you are selecting the company name, telling it to `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PRICE DESC)` would have the row with the highest PRICE as #1, the second highest as #2, etc.

I suggest you to check the [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0023461.htm) and come back with an example of what you have done so far so we can start from there.

Comment: in second row should be the sum of sales of:
sales with bigger price(1)
plus sum of all sales with lower price (2+3). get it?

Comment: so I have a table calls orders for example in this table I have these values
   name    volume    price
1- Cisco    300       27
2- Cisco    150       26
3- Cisco     50       26

I am trying to use this query:

select o.name, sum(o2.volume), o.price
from orders o, orders o2
where o.price <= o2.price
group by o.name, o.price

but this query returns this:

   name    volume    price
1- Cisco    300       27
2- Cisco    200       26

But I want this results:

   name    volume    price
1- Cisco    300       27
2- Cisco    500       26

Answer (score 0):

I got it, so I did this:

select 
o.name, 
(select sum(o2.volume) from orders o2
                where  o2.price <= o.price
                       and o2.name = o.name),
,o.price
from orders o
group by o.name, o.price